# Angular 6 RxJS, subscriber not getting value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a login.component

```js
  login() {
    this.accountService.login(this.model)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
            //do stuff
        },
        (error: AppError) => {
         // do stuff
        },  
      );
```

a login service

```js
   login(loginModel: LoginModel) {
    return this.http.post('auth/login/', loginModel).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        if (response) {
         //add jwt to local storage
         }
     }));
     }
```

and a httpinterceptor

```js
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const headerSettings: { [ name: string ]: string | string[]; } = {};

    return this.localStorage.getItem(AppStorageKeys.JWT).pipe(
      mergeMap((token: any) => {
        if (token)
          //add to headers etc

        const apiReq = req.clone({ url: `${environment.apiBase}/${req.url}`, headers: newHeader });
        return next.handle(apiReq);
      }));
     }
```

When login fails the login.component shows the error. When login is successful, the token is retrieved from the api successfully, as I can see from the network tab in dev tools, but the value is never stored in the map function in login.service nor is the response => {} function called within the login.component.ts - yet error does?

What am I doing wrong?

----- Edit:

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xerzao?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccount.service.ts) but it is working on there, which is leading me to believe it might be because my login.component and service are in a child module, to the interceptor.

Comment: shouldnt it be `this.http.post(.....)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "never stored in the map function"?

Comment: you seem to have custom implementations of localStorage, because setItemSubscribe isn't a native function and getItem doesnt natively return an observable.  What are these implementations? the error could be happening in there.

Comment: @bryan60 that is from this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage)
I've taked that out and the login.component.ts still doesn't get anything in the subscription response.

Comment: @martin - sorry I meant tap function in the login.service

Comment: what happens if you remove the interceptor entirely

Comment: @bryan60 same outcome

Comment: @Jackmagic1 What does the error say?

Comment: you said error func is called in login.component. Log that error on console.

Comment: @AbdulRafayif i purposely input an invalid login for example, the 400 error is resolved. But any 200 errors are not 'making it' to the response function within the login.component subscription

Comment: oh my bad. Your code seems fine(I think). Can you replicate the problem on stackblitz so that we can help?

Comment: what is actually the response from the server? if it's not JSON, you might have to change something in your request, see: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

Comment: I've added a stickblitz

Comment: @ggradnig that was the solution, my api was returning a string authkey but not as a json object. THANKY OU

Comment: you're welcome, was a lucky guess :) I'll add it as an anwser ;)

Comment: would be happy if you could accept the answer, it might help people in a similiar situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, Angular 6 `HttpClient` will only accept JSON as a response per default. In order to change the acceptable response type, add a third parameter to the `post` function call, like so:

```
return this.http.post('auth/login/', loginModel, {responseType: 'text'})
```

More info on that can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data